# Do not create AWS SNS Topic if it does not already exist

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am using AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService (C#) for AWS SNS service. We have a custom Publish method which is used to publish messages to SNS. The publish message currently looks something like the below snippet:

```
public void Publish(string topicName, string message)
{
    //private readonly IAmazonSimpleNotificationService _snsClient; (just showing how _snsClient is created)
    var result = await _snsClient.CreateTopicAsync(_topicName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    snsClient.Publish(message);

}
```

It creates a new topic if it already does not exist.

I know CreateTopicAsync is idempotent and will create the topic and return a response with the ARN if the topic does not already exist.

**My Use Case**:
I want the topic to be **NOT** created, if it does not already exist. Any pointers?

**What I have explored?**

- GetTopicAttributesAsync -> This function returns the attributes of a topic if one exists, otherwise returns a 404 exception. This might be a good way to check if the topic already exists or not, but the problem is that it accepts the topic ARN, unlike CreateTopicAsync which accepts the topicName. My problem is, I cannot possibly have the topicARN since I do not know whether the topic yet exists or not(Infact, that is what I want to do)

My intention was to do something like the below, except that the GetTopicAttributesAsync method will not accept the topicName. Hence, I am getting blocked:

```
public void Publish(string topicName, string message)
{
    //private readonly IAmazonSimpleNotificationService _snsClient; (just showing how _snsClient is created)
    var topicAttributes = await _snsClient.GetTopicAttributesAsync(topicName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (topicAttributes.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"SNS topic '{topicName}' does not exist. Not creating a new one.");

            }
    snsclient.Publish(message);
    return;
}
```

**Question**:

1. Is there any other way to apart from GetTopicAttributesAsync to check if the topic exists?
2. Is there a way to use CreateTopicAsync but not create the topic if it does not already exist?

Comment: If you know the `topicName`, you can construct its arn yourself.

Comment: @Marcin - That is a good idea. But we have multiple environments and our usual ARN names have env name prefixes, with region names as well. Will be difficult to construct one. Any other way?

Comment: Don't know at present.  SDK can give you your current region, and topicName is already passed to `Publish`. I don't quite understand the `env` prefixes for arn? What is that?